# Disabling Mouse Right Click On Image Control VB6

Tags: vb6, mouseevent

Ok, after searching for an hour, I still haven't found the right answer for this. All I want is to disable the right click on my button because it's creating a bug, according to our tester. I don't know if VB6 can't do this, but if VB6 can't do this, is there any possible way? Ok, just to be more specific, here is my example...

'I found this somewhere...

```
Private Sub cmdExportCSV_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
   If Button = vbRightButton Then
       'Do Nothing
   End If
End Sub


'Then I have here
Private Sub cmdExportCSV_Click()
   'Some logic here
End Sub
```

But when I click the right button on my mouse, the cmdExportCSV_Click() still executing the code inside.

Comment: Could you please specify what kind of button are you using? VB6 CommandButtons aren't RMB clickable.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this then (based upon your code):

```
Private m_mouseButton As Integer

Private Sub cmdExportCSV_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
   m_mouseButton = Button
End Sub

Private Sub cmdExportCSV_Click()
   If m_mouseButton = vbRightButton Then
       'Do Nothing
       Exit Sub
   End If
   'Some logic here
End Sub
```

I didn't run this or anything, but it should work.

Comment: Where you wrote `If Button = vbRightButton` I think you meant `If m_mouseButton = vbRightButton`

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I edited to fix that.  Thanks!

Comment: @syntaxerror , please let us know if this resolved your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved my own problem.

From this..

```
Private Sub cmdExportCSV_Click()
   If m_mouseButton = vbRightButton Then
       'Do Nothing
       Exit Sub
   End If
   'Some logic here
End Sub
```

To this..

```
Private Sub cmdExportCSV_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button And vbRightButton Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
   'Some logic here
End Sub
```

That's it! VB6 won't directly allow you to disable the mouse right and mouse left button. My solution is just to exit event whenever the user click the mouse right button.

Anyway, I'm sorry as I found out that the system is using asImageCommand not CommandButton, so when you declare an event like this "Private Sub cmdExportCSV_Click()", the asImageCommand control will trigger when you click the mouse-right and mouse-left button. But if you are using CommandButton, it will only trigger when you click the left-button, and won't allow you to use the right-button of the mouse.

I think I have to update the title of my question.